# Deleting an element from a list in a dictionary

Tags: list, dictionary, del

This:

```
deck = {1:[1,2,3,4], 2:[1,2,3,4], 3:[1,2,3,4]}    
print(deck)
del deck[1][2]
print(deck)
```

gives this:

{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]}

{1: [1, 2, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]}

which is what I expect, but this:

```
deck = {1:None, 2:None, 3:None}
suit =[1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(deck)):
deck[i+1] = suit      
print(deck)
del deck[1][2]
print(deck)
```

gives this:

{1: [1, 2, 3, 4], 2: [1, 2, 3, 4], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]}

{1: [1, 2, 4], 2: [1, 2, 4], 3: [1, 2, 4]}

As you can see the del keyword deletes index 2 for every key value, not just key value 1.
Sorry if this is obvious, I'm learning and confused by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in the dict has a reference to **the same** list. So when you delete an element from one of them, it's visible via all of them (since, as noted, they're actually the same list!).

Instead, each element of the dict should have a different copy of the list:

```py
for i in range(len(deck)):
    deck[i+1] = suit[:]
```

Side note:
This loop could be replaced with a more "pythonic" dict-comprehension:

```py
deck = {i:suit[:] for i in range(1,4)}
```

Comment: So  I need to copy contents not the list itself. That works. Thanks Mureinik